# Set combobox value after loading json store

Tags: extjs4

I have a Combobox which I am loading it from controller (code snippet below)

```
Ext.getCmp("combovalue2").getStore().loadRawData(value2);
```

`value2` is the object that I get from model and it works successfully (I verified this  onclick of combobox). Below is the code snippet for combobox in my form panel

```
{
                xtype:'combo',
                id:"combovalue2",
                name: 'cpa',
                cls:'extraComboBox',
                forceSelection: true,
                queryMode: 'local',
                fieldLabel: 'Alliance',
                displayField: 'label',     
                valueField: 'numAe',
                emptyText: 'select Alliance',
                store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({fields: ["numAe","label"]})
           }
```

This is how my json looks like

```
"cpaList": [
        {
            "label": "A Communications                   ",
            "id": "USF  ",
            "numOff": 999,
            "numAe": 483,
            "pctFeeCalc": 0,
            "pctFeeBasisPoint": 0
        },
        {
            "label": "Ac Neilson, Inc                    ",
            "id": "MMV  ",
            "numOff": 999,
            "numAe": 876,
            "pctFeeCalc": 20,
            "pctFeeBasisPoint": 0
        },
        {
            "label": "Acer Worldwide Inc.                ",
            "id": "CAA  ",
            "numOff": 999,
            "numAe": 619,
            "pctFeeCalc": 0,
            "pctFeeBasisPoint": 0
        },
        {
            "label": "Advantech, Inc.                    ",
            "id": "SLE  ",
            "numOff": 999,
            "numAe": 592,
            "pctFeeCalc": 0,
            "pctFeeBasisPoint": 0
        },
        {
            "label": "Afo Ltd                            ",
            "id": "NAN  ",
            "numOff": 999,
            "numAe": 959,
            "pctFeeCalc": 25,
            "pctFeeBasisPoint": 0
        },
        {
            "label": "All Systems Go                     ",
            "id": "BCS  ",
            "numOff": 999,
            "numAe": 944,
            "pctFeeCalc": 25,
            "pctFeeBasisPoint": 0
        },
        {
            "label": "Alyssa Anne Lock                   ",
            "id": "GRE  ",
            "numOff": 999,
            "numAe": 369,
            "pctFeeCalc": 20,
            "pctFeeBasisPoint": 0
        }
```

]

Model

```
{name: 'cpa', mapping: 'cpaList'}
```

But i have a hard time displaying the value that should be displayed when the combobox is rendered. I want to set value to the combobox that comes from json (this means value2 is an array of object and the one that i want to set is a string) and at the same time also display the array of data in combobox that i am doing via `loadRawData(value2)`.

Comment: Well, i am able to display an array of objects via loadRawData(value2) eg ["A", "B","C", "D", "E"] these values are getting displayed on load of combobox. But apart from that i need to setValue as "B" and this value comes from the database dynamically. So i have to set the value as "B" and also display "A", "B","C", "D", "E" in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to loadRawData.  From the looks of your code, your store needs to be changed or you need to use a portion of your JSON data being returned.

Your root is 'cpaList'.  The store doesn't know what to do with this. If you want to keep your code the way it is, then do the following:

```
Ext.getCmp("combovalue2").getStore().loadData(value2.cpaList);
```

Otherwise you will have to change your store to match your data.  If you actually define this store instead and then set your combo store to the defined store, it will autoLoad on render instead.  Then you don't have to fire a separate AJAX request and your code is all related to your store now.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/whateveryoururlis',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'cpaList' // your root of your data containing the array of fields for the store
        }
    },
    fields: ["numAe","label"]
});
```

Comment: Loading of data to combobox is fine. I am done with it. But the problem i have is setting a value to the store after the load is done. I have one object in the json from which i have to compare it with value2 object and then setting it to the combo from controller. Below is the code that is setting the value but it doesnot show up on UI                                      Ext.each(value2, function (item, idx, a) {
              if(item.numAe === cpaNo){
               console.log(item.label);
               numAe = item.numAe;
               label = item.label;
              }
             })

Comment: Are item.numAe and cpaNo both the same types? I see that item.numAe is a Number is cpaNo also a Number. If not, you'll never get a match using '==='.  Also, you're doing an each() on value2. Is it even iterating over the array? Your JSON says value2 is key cpaList not an array. If this isn't the case, can you give a better example?

Comment: Yes, both item.numAe and cpaNo are of similar types. I have below piece of code and when i alert the value i can see it. Here is the piece of code below.                         Ext.each(value2, function (item, idx, a) {
              if(item.numAe === cpaNo){
               console.log(item.label);
               Ext.getCmp("combovalue2").setValue(item.numAe);
               Ext.getCmp("combovalue2").setRawValue(item.label);
               alert(Ext.getCmp("combovalue2").getValue());
               alert(Ext.getCmp("combovalue2").getRawValue());
              }
             })

Comment: Why do you keep using setRawValue()? This will bypass any validation done by ExtJS. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/PWQLU/

Comment: Ok, i removed setRawValue() and observed one thing. If i use setValue and put an alert for getValue() i can see the combobox set the value for some time and then resets the value to default "select Alliance". Does it have something to do with form.loadRecord(model)  as i am trying to set the value on form laod.

Comment: There could be a lot of factors. I haven't seen the rest of your code so it's hard to say.  If you're trying to load values into a form, you probably want to use Ext.getCmp('formid').getForm().setValues([{OBJECT},{OBJECT}],...) with the key being the name on each form field.  Also, if you are trying to do a loadRecord() why are setting the value of the combo in the first place? Then you're just calling setValue() on the combo twice.

Comment: The reason why i am setting the value explicitly is - "cpaList" is the static object that will get displayed always in the dropdown but apart from that there is an another object that i have to set when any value from the "cpaList" is selected and saved to db. When i load the form i should be able to see the one that i last choose and the saved one comes in a different object than "cpaList" although it is a part of the same json.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this.
I took 2 different objects in model one is to load the store via loadData(modelObject) and then the other that retains the value in combobox – name config ie cpa.

Model Defn:

```
{name: 'cpaList', mapping: 'cpaList'},
{name: 'cpa', mapping: 'feeSetupCtg.cpaNo'}
```

Controller Defn:

```
var value2 = model.get('cpaList');
Ext.getCmp("combovalue2").getStore().loadData(value2);
```

Combobox defn:

```
{
    xtype:'combo',
    id:"combovalue2",
    name: 'cpa',
    cls:'extraComboBox',
    forceSelection: true,
    queryMode: 'local',
    fieldLabel: 'Alliance',
    displayField: 'label',     
    valueField: 'numAe',
    emptyText: 'select Alliance',
    editable: false,
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({fields: ["numAe","label"]})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your controller:

```
Ext.getCmp("combovalue2").getStore().on("load", this.setDefaultComboValue, this);

...

setDefaultComboValue: function(store, records, successful, eOpts)
{
   if(successful){
        Ext.getCmp("combovalue2").setValue(records[0]); //records[0] or whatever record you want to load
   }
}
```

Do note that in Extjs 4.2 the loadRawData method doesn't fire the load event any more.
I recommend you use the load method to load your JSON data.